# wmic output empty when run from batchfile, but contains info when run from cmd

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, wmi, wmic

I have this wmic command which finds out the PID of my process and works fine from cmd, but refuses to produce output when executed in a bat-file:

```
wmic /output:process.pid process where (Name like '%java%' and commandLine like '%part-of-the-path%') get ProcessId
```

When I run it from cmd, it produces a file containing

```
ProcessId
19352
```

The info is followed by two blank lines. When I run it from a batch-file, it only produces a file with two blank lines.

I tried `/output:filename`, `> filename` and `| more > filename`, all with the same result.

Why is this? How to make the command produce output from the batch?

Comment: In batch file, are you replacing `%` with `%%`? `%jave%` on command prompt must be `%%java%%` in batch file.

Comment: `%java%` is not set beforehand. Like SQL, wmic uses this as an asterisk matching any text. I don't want batch to interpret the string, but just give it to wmic as is. The solution from @Sandeep seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like most of programming languages, a batch file also has escape characters. `%` sign used in command line is an escape character in batch file and give the command a different meaning.  It is actually looking for a variable named `%java%`.

To resolve this problem, use `%%` instead of `%` in batch file.  To see more details and information on other escape character look [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php).

Following command should work in batch file.

`wmic /output:process.pid process where (Name like '%%java%%' and commandLine like '%%part-of-the-path%%') get ProcessId`